# .NET MVC Custom viewengine layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, layout, viewengine

In a custom viewengine in the `FindView` method, how can I see the `Layout` used? `masterName` is always empty.

```cs
ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewName, string masterName, bool useCache) {
    // How do I get WebViewPage.Layout to know what layout is used?
}
```

Comment: `FindView` method of what class?

Comment: @jrummell it's part of [IViewEngine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iviewengine.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are setting your master at the controller level with `return View(string viewName, string masterName)`, the `masterName` will always be empty. The master is *typically* determined during the compilation of the view itself.